# Magento 1.5 CE Newsletter don't send

Tags: magento, newsletter

The Newsletter is not sent in Magento CE v.15
I understand I need to set-up some sort of Cron to send newsletter. But isnt Cron (scheduled task) already built in under back end Systems>Congfiguration>Advance>System?

(I have enabled MailChimp if that could be a problem?)

Please advise or point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need add cron.sh to your server crontab. More info you can read in this [article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job#cron.sh).

Comment: Thank you. I did read the link you suggested. We are on Virtual hosting so I ended up setting Cron Job through Cpanel. I am not sure if shared hosting allows this option. I believe different hosting company has different ways of setting Cron Job using Cpanel so just check their Knowledgebase (documentation). Hope this helps other people.